# Retrieve data (iCalUId) from newly created event

Tags: list, events, sharepoint, outlook, power-automate

I'm trying to synchronize a sharepoint list and an outlook calendar through power automate flows.

Following several posts here and there, I managed to successfully create 2 flows:

1. When an event is created or modified in outlook  an item is created or updated in the sharepoint list. To link the two I'm storing `iCalUId` from the outlook event into an `eventID` column in the sharepoint list.
2. When an item is modified in the sharepoint lost, the event is updated in the outllok calendar, again, using `eventID` <-> `iCalUId` as a link/key

What I need now is to create an outlook event when a new SP item is created. I am stuck at the point where after creating the outlook event, I would need to retrieve back the `iCalUId` from the newly created event, and store that back in the item in the list.

Any idea or hint on how to do that would be great ;-)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you directly use the calendar app in the classic mode in SharePoint, and then select **Connect to Outlook** to synchronize the two calendars.
For more information, please refer to:
https://www.rrc.ca/its/help-resources/sharepoint/connect-sharepoint-calendar-to-outlook-calendar/
https://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/connect-sharepoint-2013-calendar-to-your-outlook-calendar

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately, the "Connect to Outlook" functionnality has been disabled by my admin, and no chance to have access to it soon ... :-( that's why i'm trying to find workarounds !

Comment: Oh, sorry. Have a good luck.